# GitLab and Redis on Ubuntu 14.04: resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, gitlab

My GitLab worked fine, until today. Now I get `500` error on the front page of GitLab. So I look at the log (`/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log`) and see this line:

```
Errno::EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable - connect(2) for /var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket):
```

Of course I've tried commands like these:

```
$ sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
$ sudo gitlab-ctl kill redis
$ sudo gitlab-ctl start
$ sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

and so on, but it doesn't help.

What can I do? I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hmm... I kill `runsv redis` process, and after that do `sudo gitlab-ctl stop redis` and `sudo gitlab-ctl restart redis`. And now all fine... Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar situation, and **kill `runsv redis` also works for me**.

I'm using RHEL 6.6 and GitLab suddenly doesn't work. Every page shows 404. The error I `gitlab-ctl restart` is `redis got TERM`. After extensive searching and reconfig, restart, updating etc, there is always some redis error.

However kill `runsv redis` works; I hope this will help others.